# Key Error Running Python Script (Using Atom)

Tags: python, api, atom-editor, keyerror, riot-games-api

I have never used python before. I'm following a [short guide on how to use an API with Python](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-riot-api-with-python-b93be82dbbd6). I'm using Atom text editor plus the [Hydrogen module](https://towardsdatascience.com/atoms-hydrogen-for-writing-data-science-projects-using-python-46b6507fcdf7) to run said code.

I am getting KeyError: '203' when I run the following segment.

```
champ_dict = {}
for key in static_champ_list['data']:
        row = static_champ_list['data'][key]
    champ_dict[row['key']] = row['id']
for row in participants:
        print(str(row['champion']) + ' ' + champ_dict[str(row['champion'])])
    row['championName'] = champ_dict[str(row['champion'])]

    # print dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(participants)
df
```

the error occurs on the following line

```
     print(str(row['champion']) + ' ' + champ_dict[str(row['champion'])])
```

I get that it's lookup error but I'm lost as how to resolve it.

Here is the full version of my code

```
    #Test Script for interacting with
    #RIOT API

#Built from 'Towards Data Science' guide

#If you want to use Hydrogen, install
#the Hydrogen Package and run
# python3 -m pip install ipykernel
# python3 -m ipykernel install --user
#This might allow pandas, idk

#-------------------------------------------

    #Get installed module for Python
import riotwatcher

    #Import tools.
from riotwatcher import LolWatcher, ApiError

    #Import pandas
import pandas as pd

    # Global variables
# Get new API from
# https://developer.riotgames.com/
api_key = 'RGAPI-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX'
watcher = LolWatcher(api_key)
my_region = 'euw1'

    #Use 'watcher' to get basic stats
me = watcher.summoner.by_name(my_region, 'RGE lnspired')
print(me)

    #Use 'watcher' to get ranked ranked stats
my_ranked_stats = watcher.league.by_summoner(my_region, me['id'])
print(my_ranked_stats)




    # Setup retrieval of match info
my_matches = watcher.match.matchlist_by_account(my_region, me['accountId'])

    # Fetch info about last match
last_match = my_matches['matches'][0]
match_detail = watcher.match.by_id(my_region, last_match['gameId'])

    #Setup Data Frame to view some of this stuff
participants = []
for row in match_detail['participants']:
        participants_row = {}
        participants_row['champion'] = row['championId']
        participants_row['spell1'] = row['spell1Id']
        participants_row['spell2'] = row['spell2Id']
        participants_row['win'] = row['stats']['win']
        participants_row['kills'] = row['stats']['kills']
        participants_row['deaths'] = row['stats']['deaths']
        participants_row['assists'] = row['stats']['assists']
        participants_row['totalDamageDealt'] = row['stats']['totalDamageDealt']
        participants_row['goldEarned'] = row['stats']['goldEarned']
        participants_row['champLevel'] = row['stats']['champLevel']
        participants_row['totalMinionsKilled'] = row['stats']['totalMinionsKilled']
        participants_row['item0'] = row['stats']['item0']
        participants_row['item1'] = row['stats']['item1']
        participants.append(participants_row)
df = pd.DataFrame(participants)
df



#So now we can look at what is referred
#to as 'Static Data'

    # check league's latest version
latest = watcher.data_dragon.versions_for_region(my_region)['n']['champion']
    # Lets get some champions static information
static_champ_list = watcher.data_dragon.champions(latest, False, 'en_US')

    # champ static list data to dict for looking up
champ_dict = {}
for key in static_champ_list['data']:
        row = static_champ_list['data'][key]
    champ_dict[row['key']] = row['id']
for row in participants:
        print(str(row['champion']) + ' ' + champ_dict[str(row['champion'])])
    row['championName'] = champ_dict[str(row['champion'])]

    # print dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(participants)
df
```

Comment: it means that the key `'203'` is not a valid key for the dictionary `champ_dict`. You can see all of the keys by printing out `champ_dict.keys()`

Comment: Thank you @vlovero, that one command makes my life so much easier. I know it's an easy question but if you just post that I will gladly mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to retrieve a value from a standard dictionary in python with a key, it must be a valid or else a `KeyError` will be raised. So your code is attempting to use the key `'203'` with the dictionary `champ_dict`, however `'203'` is not a valid key (hence the `KeyError`). To see which keys are currently present in the dict, you can call the `dict.keys` method on `champ_dict`. Example would be something like

```
>>> champ_dict = {'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2', 'key3': 'val3'}
>>> champ_dict.keys()
dict_keys(['key1', 'key2', 'key3'])
```